# How do SQL Server computed columns work in EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I have a table whose column `TotalAmount` is a computed column from columns `Amount+Extra`, so how this computation works, if I use Entity Framework on this table?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it not giving you the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A computed column is either (a) recalculated every time you access it, or (b) if you defined it with the `PERSISTED` keyword, an actual column is created in your table's data pages and the value is stored there.

In any way, to Entity Framework, both kinds of computed columns should behave just like regular columns. If Entity Framework accesses the table and reads data from it, it should get the current value of `TotalAmount` and store it in your entity's corresponding property.

When you create an ADO.NET Entity Data Model from a database, EF will pick up that the column is a *computed* column, and thus you won't be able to set a new value for that property (obviously):

[image]

Comment: Based on your screenshot, it looks like a setter will be defined for the computed column. I'm assuming it will let you set that in code, and just either ignore it when interacting with the database or throw an error?

Comment: @Gromer: you can actually indeed set the value of the computed column as far as your C# object goes - but that's not being stored in the database table. When you call `.SaveChanges()`, the computed column's values are *not* sent to the database - that wouldn't make sense. The other column's values are set, and thus the computed column in the database table gets evaluated.

Comment: Yeah, ignoring it makes the most sense to me.  I've not used computed columns with EF before, I just was curious as to if it would throw an exception if you did set it. Thanks for the info!

Comment: I suppose we should be grateful it does even this much, but it does seem mighty odd that it generates a setter at all...

Answer (score 3):

In addition the response by marc_s it is important to note that changing the underlying properties of the EF entity will not recalculate the value unless you save the object and then refresh it from the database. Put another way, the property on the C# object does not implement the calculation from the database.